# Is the German CDU 26-point migration plan publically available?

Tags: germany, immigration, reference-request

The CDU (currently the biggest opposition party in Germany) handed the government a 26-point plan with their demands on the topic of migration. It seems like every major newspaper has an article on it ([Zeit](https://www.zeit.de/politik/deutschland/2023-10/deutschland-kanzler-migration-merz-cdu), [Spiegel](https://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/migration-treffen-mit-olaf-scholz-friedrich-merz-legt-26-punkte-papier-vor-a-6277d468-260a-46ff-9db1-3c80056bdc8d), [Süddeutsche](https://www.sueddeutsche.de/politik/migration-gipfel-union-forderungen-1.6287611)) and all of them cite from the plan. But I couldn't find the actual plan in any of them and the CDU website doesn't seem to have the plan either. Is this plan available somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On its campaign website [deutschlandpakt.de](https://deutschlandpakt.cducsu.de/), the parliamentary group of CDU/CSU links the paper under the heading "Unsere Vorschläge für den #Deutschlandpakt": https://www.cducsu.de/sites/default/files/2023-10/FILE_7593.pdf.